# Using my second computer as proxy

Tags: networking, windows, proxy

I'm on Windows 10. I want to use my second computer as a proxy. I have to set this command in my cmd: `netsh winhttp set proxy 10.10.10.10:1111`. My question is which IP address and port number do I need? How can I get those information from my second computer?

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the actual second computer runs. For instance, another Win10 workstation would not be able to provide proxy services, since it is not natively supported. It is most likely possible to install a third party software that would act as the proxy, but ideally I would look into a dedicated proxy server solution such as [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) that you could run on a VM or container on your LAN.

In this case, the IP would be the IP address of the VM/container and the default port to use for Squid would be 3128.